# Working with multiple arrays after splitting (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create a web page that takes data from a CVS file and creates a custom  for each row of content in the CSV file. I used jQuery to import CSV file and split the data it into an array:

```
promise = $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    dataType:"text",
    url:"data.csv",
    cache:false
});

promise.done(function(data){

    //Parse CSV File
    //split on new line
    var dataArr = data.split("\n");
    console.log(dataArr);
```

Then I am using $.each to split each line into an array.

```
    //for each line in array
    $.each(dataArr,function(){
         var valArr = this.split(",");
```

[screenshot of arrays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTuhS.png)

After that, I would like to take each created array and use it for creating my custom  element. However, I can't figure out how to access each created array individually. If I access first item in the array by using valArr[0], I get results for the entire column A (instead of row 1, column A) in my CSV file. I'm new to Javascript, so I'm completely stuck here. Please point me in the right direction.

Thank you!

Update: added the HTML code I am using to insert the data from each row into.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <!--Content start -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">

            <!--Catalog content start  -->
            <div class="col">
                <div class="row allMyContent">

                    <!-- Card start -->

                    <div class='card mb-4 box-shadow col-5 ml-4'>
                        <div class="card-header" style="background-color: #fff;">
                            <!-- Link 1, 2, 3 etc go here (id #contentLink) -->
                            <a href="#" class="float-right ml-3" id="copyLink" id="contentLink">Link 1</a>
                            <!-- Course 1, 2, 3 etc go here (id #contentTitle) -->
                            <h5 class="my-0 font-weight-normal mr-5" id="contentTitle">Course 1</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div>
                                <!-- Time and type go here (id #contentLength and #contentType) -->
                                <p><span class="mr-2" id='contentType'>Type 1</span> | <span class="ml-2"><span id='contentLength'></span> 20 min</span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <!-- Description goes here (id #contentDescription) -->
                                <p id='contentDescription'>Description 1</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer row" style="font-size: 0.85em;">
                            <!-- Audience, dates goe here (id #contentAudience #date1 #date2) -->
                            <small class="col" id='contentAudience'>Audience: HR</small>
                            <small class="col" id='date1'>Created: Jul-17</small>
                            <small class="col" id='date2'>Updated: Dec-17</small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Card end -->

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you got the `.split()` done right. To recap:

- `.split("\n")` will get you CSV **lines** Array (your `dataArr`)
- for looping `dataArr` you have access to each **individual line** (I'll use JS's `.map()`)
- splitting each line using `.split(",")` will give you an array of **cells**
- for looping your cells will give you access to each **individual cell** (let's use `.map()` again)

```js
// I'll hardcode this CSV data; you, use AJAX as you do already...
const data = `Course A,Link 1,Type1,20,Description 1,HR,Jul-17,Dec-17
Course B,Link 2,Type1,30,Description 2,HR,Oct-17,Dec-18
Course C,Link 3,Type2,60,Description 3,HR,Nov-17,Dec-19`;

const dataArr = data.split("\n");


// let's create rows and cells
document.getElementById("courses").innerHTML = dataArr.map( row => 
  // row is still a comma concatenated string.
  // Let's split by comma to get cells
  `<tr>
     ${ row.split(",").map( cell => `<td>${cell}</td>`).join("") }
   </tr>`
).join(""); // join rows Array into String;
```

```css
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
th, td{
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Course</th>
      <th>Link</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Duration</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>CC</th>
      <th>From</th>
      <th>To</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="courses"></tbody>
</table>
```

If the above seems a bit cryptic here's an example with `Array.prototype.forEach()`

```js
// I'll hardcode this CSV data; you, use AJAX as you do already...
const data = `Course A,Link 1,Type1,20,Description 1,HR,Jul-17,Dec-17
Course B,Link 2,Type1,30,Description 2,HR,Oct-17,Dec-18
Course C,Link 3,Type2,60,Description 3,HR,Nov-17,Dec-19`;

const lines = data.split("\n");

let HTML = ""; // We'll concatenate HTML string along the way

// let's create rows and cells
lines.forEach(function(line, i) {     // Concatenate rows

  const items = line.split(",");      // (our Array of cells)
  
  HTML += "<tr>";                     // open row 
  HTML += "<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td>"      // Insert a hardcoded TD with index
   
  items.forEach(function(item, j) {   // than concatenate our remaining cells
    HTML += "<td>"+ item +"</td>";    
  });
  
  HTML += "</tr>";                    // Close row

});

document.getElementById("courses").innerHTML = HTML; // Finally, append our HTML string
```

```css
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
th, td{
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Course</th>
      <th>Link</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Duration</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>CC</th>
      <th>From</th>
      <th>To</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="courses"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Roko, this is super helpful! I'm trying to do more than just a table with this data though. I am trying to create a boostrap card and need to pul my data into specific place in HTML. I attached my html and also screenshot. Any suggestion how I can do it?

Comment: Roko - I added the html code into my original post.

Answer (score 0):

if `valArr[0]` contains whole A column why not iterate over it like this:

```
for(var column = 0; column < valArr.length; column++){
    var currentColumn = valArr[column];
    for(var item = 0; item < currentColumn.length; item++){
       console.log(currentColumn[item]);
    }
}
```

code above will iterate every column and over every item in every column, if  you want to save whole row in variable you can do it like this:

```
function getRow(varArr, id){
    var retval = [];
    for(var column = 0; column < valArr.length; column++){
        var currentColumn = valArr[column];
        retval.push(currentColumn[id]); //add some checking if id is really present in this array
    }
    return retval;
}
```

code above will return something like this:
`[column_A_item_with_id, column_B_item_with_id, column_C_item_with_id, ...]`

Comment: Thank you for suggestions and your help! I tried plugging the code and doesn't seems to work. What I am trying to do is to simply select Array 1 and then select item 1 (then 2,3,4 etc) in that Array and plug that item in the array into my div. However, after split, I get three arrays assigned to one variable (see screenshot in the original post). I am not sure how to split the array into separate array now so I can access each value.

Comment: are those arrays correct or not? I mean, is it correct that field one has to contain 'course a' and field next to it has to contain 'link 1' etc?

Comment: Yes, correct. Each array individually has exactly the data I need. However, I can't figure out how to access each item individually (i.e. course 1, course 2, course 3 - these will be heading for each <div>,). When I try to access them individually, I get all first items in the array together (i.e. Course 1 Course 2 Course 3). Hope it makes sense.

Comment: so when you get all items in one array together what's the issue? can't you just acces them like `result[0] result[1]` etc?

Comment: No, unfortunately, I can't. I added the html where I am trying to insert the results into the original post. I am trying to take a specific item into the new split array and insert it in the specific place in my boostrap card.

Answer (score 0):

After modifying the code suggested by Roko and spending a bunch of time trying to figure out why it's not working, I realized I wasn't building the HTMl correctly. Here is the final result.

```js
const data = `Course A,Link 1,Type1,20,Description 1,HR,Jul-17,Dec-17
Course B,Link 2,Type1,30,Description 2,HR,Oct-17,Dec-18
Course C,Link 3,Type2,60,Description 3,HR,Nov-17,Dec-19`;

const dataArr = data.split("\n");

        //Parse CSV File
        //split on new line
        const lines = data.split("\n");


        let HTML = '';

        //for each line in array
        lines.forEach(function(line, i) {
            var contentCards = line.split(",");
            HTML += '<div class="card mb-4 box-shadow col-5 ml-4">';
            HTML += '<div class="card-header">'
            HTML += '<h5 class="my-0 font-weight-normal mr-5" style="color: #ff8f00;">'
            HTML += '<a href="'
            HTML += contentCards[1];
            HTML += '" class="float-right ml-3" id="copyLink" style="color: #00a4b4; font-size: 1.2rem;"><i class="fas fa-external-link-square-alt"></i></a>'
            HTML += '<a href="'
            HTML += contentCards[1];
            HTML += '"class="float-right" style="color: #00a4b4; font-size: 1.2rem;"><i class="fas fa-link"></i></a>'
            HTML += contentCards[0];
            HTML += '</h5>'
            HTML += '</div>'
            HTML += '<div class="card-body">'
            HTML += '<div>'
            HTML += '<div class="card-body">'
            HTML += '<p><span class="mr-2">'
            HTML += '  <p><span class="mr-2 contentType">'
            HTML += contentCards[2];
            HTML += '</span>|<span class="ml-2"><i class="far fa-clock"></i ><span>'
            HTML += contentCards[3];
            HTML += ' min</span >'
            HTML += '</p>'
            HTML += '</div>'
            HTML += '<p>'
            HTML += contentCards[4];
            HTML += '</p>'
            HTML += '</div>'
            HTML += '<div class = "card-footer row" style = "font-size: 0.85em;" >'
            HTML += '</div>'
            HTML += '</p>'
            HTML += '</div>'
            HTML += '</div>'

            document.getElementById("courses").innerHTML = HTML;

        });
        console.log(HTML);
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<div id="courses">

</div>
```

Comment: No, don't use innerHTML inside a loop! See how `console.log(HTML)` returns properly *outside* of the loop? Use it there! Also, you could make use of tempalte literals: http://jsbin.com/qoqecuh/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Wow, this is much easier solution. Lot it. Thank you very much, Roko!

Comment: Can you post your code as a comment so I can vote it as a correct answer?

Comment: I would like to learn more about the syntax you used to select the item in the array ${contentCards[5]}. I tried to Google it but didn't see anything. Is it jQuery or pure JavaScript?

Comment: it's ES6's Template Literals. Just like strings but more powerful since it allows multiline templateing and simple variables inclusion using the `${}` wrapper. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals